# Pop value from if less than x

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array of dictionaries

```
for row in array:
        if row['val'] < 11:
            array.pop(array.index(row))
```

in which I am trying to remove the dictionary from the array if one of its values is below a certain threshold. It works, but only for one of the items in the array

My solution right now is to run the for statement twice, which then removes the extra value. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You [shouldn't modify a collection that you're iterating over](https://www.google.com/search?q=modify+collection+while+iterating+python). Instead, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
array = [row for row in array if row['val'] >= 11]
```

Also, let's clear up one other thing. Python [doesn't have native arrays](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html). It has lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
[el for el in array if test_to_be_preserved(el)]
```

Where `test_to_be_preserved` is a function that return `True` if `el` should be spared, and `False` if `el` should be removed from the `array`

Or, if you don't mind changing order of elements in your original array:

```
  i = 0
  while i < len(array):
    el = array[i]
    if should_remove(el):
        array[i] = array.pop()
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: Yes, it's a useful trick of O(1) element removal from a vector (i've used it pretty often with std c++ vectors) if you don't mind the order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> nums = [random.randint(1, 101) for x in xrange(20)]
>>> nums
[75, 101, 21, 69, 44, 98, 50, 45, 63, 73, 8, 44, 54, 42, 66, 68, 98, 56, 7, 36]
>>> (lambda x, l: filter(lambda y: y >= x, l))(25, nums)
[75, 101, 69, 44, 98, 50, 45, 63, 73, 44, 54, 42, 66, 68, 98, 56, 36]
```